# imagebutton causing bootstrap modal to disappear

Tags: asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap, imagebutton

I have a bootstrap modal which holds a gridview which has a templatefield that holds 3 image buttons. Whenever I click on an image button, the modal disappears but leaves the background still visible. I got one working by adding a data-dismiss="modal" as I do need to to close after being clicked. But I need the modal to stay visible after clicking the other two image buttons.

I had a similar problem with this but with an asp button which was fixed by adding a UseSubmitBehavior=false to the button. Unfortunately, the imagebutton control doesn't have this feature.

Here's the markup

```
<div id="pnlUserInfo" class="modal fade in" style="display: none;">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-1000">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">User Information</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                       <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-2">Name:</div>
                           <div class="col-lg-10"><asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="[Name]"/></div>
                       </div> 
                       <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-2">Department:</div>
                            <div class="col-lg-10"><asp:Label ID="lblDepartment" runat="server" Text="[Department]"/></div>
                       </div> 
                       <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-2">Devices Listed:</div>
                            <div class="col-lg-10"><asp:Label ID="lblDeviceCount" runat="server" Text="[Device Count]"/></div>
                       </div> 
                       <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-2">Active Devices</div>
                            <div class="col-lg-10"><asp:Label ID="lblActiveCount" runat="server" Text="[Active Device Count]"/></div>
                       </div> 
                        <div class="row">
                            <asp:GridView ID="gvwUserDevices" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CssClass="table table-hover table-bordered " 
                                DataKeyNames="ID" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" OnRowDataBound="gvwUserDevices_RowDataBound" OnRowCommand="gvwUserDevices_RowCommand"  >
                                    <Columns>
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="#" ReadOnly="True" >
                                             <ItemStyle Width="10px" Font-Size="Smaller"  />
                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Phone" DataField="Description" >
                                             <ItemStyle Font-Size="Smaller"  />
                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="MAC Address" DataField="mac" >
                                             <ItemStyle Width="125px" Font-Size="Smaller"  />
                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date Registered" DataField="DateRegistered" ReadOnly="True" >
                                        <ItemStyle Width="150px" Font-Size="Smaller" />
                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="IP Address" DataField="IPAddress" ReadOnly="True" >
                                        <ItemStyle Font-Size="Smaller" />
                                        </asp:BoundField>
                                        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Remarks" ReadOnly="True" DataField="remark" />
                                         <asp:TemplateField  >
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" CommandName="Activate"  ImageUrl="~/assets/img/icons/device-arrow-up.png" CssClass="size-20" AlternateText="Activate" ToolTip="Activate" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" CommandName="Deactivate" ImageUrl="~/assets/img/icons/device-arrow-down.png" CssClass="size-20" AlternateText="Deactivate" ToolTip="Deactivate" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
                                                 <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton4" runat="server" CommandName="Replace" ImageUrl="~/assets/img/icons/refresh.png" CssClass="size-20" AlternateText="Replace" ToolTip="Replace" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'/>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                        <asp:CommandField EditText="&lt;img src=&quot;/assets/img/icons/pencil.png&quot; class=&quot;size-25&quot; /&gt;" ShowEditButton="True" CancelText="&lt;img src=&quot;/assets/img/icons/remove.png&quot; class=&quot;size-25&quot; /&gt;" DeleteText="" UpdateText="&lt;img src=&quot;/assets/img/icons/floppy-save.png&quot; class=&quot;size-25&quot; /&gt;" >
                                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Width="80px" Font-Size="Smaller" />
                                        </asp:CommandField>
                                    </Columns>
                                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                                       <p class="text-center">No record found.</p>
                                    </EmptyDataTemplate>
                            </asp:GridView>
                       </div> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
        </div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: The region is that it is causing post-back. And if you stop post-back your servside code will not work :)

Comment: How do I trigger a postback without the modal disappearing?